# Equivalent of lseek on Linux in Windows API?

Tags: c++, windows

Is there an equivalent of `lseek` present in POSIX api on Windows? I know about `_lseek` with `io.h` but I am looking for something with WIN32 API i.e., in `Windows.h`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you're looking for [SetFilePointer()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541.aspx), or [SetFilePointerEx()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365542.aspx) if you require large file support.

Answer (score 4):

[`SetFilePointer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365541%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) would be what you are looking for.

In general, MS's website is pretty easy to search for things, by just going to a known function (such as `CreateFile`) and then going to the overview of [file functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364232%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).